# How to display more than 3 views in document library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, document-library, data-view-web-part, view

[image]

I have 4 views "All Documents" "Agreements" "Permits" "Deeds" I want to display all 4 of them above my document library but only 3 get displayed and the fourth gets placed in the "..." section. I believe this modification is possible through sharepoint designer, but I was curious if anyone knew how to achieve this through the web environment.

Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you are using SharePoint 2013 I would recommend you to consider the following approach. In SharePoint 2013 was introduced a so called `Client Rendering Mode (CSR)` which is intended for rendering of List Views and Forms using HTML and JavaScript and which is a *default rendering mode*.

**About View selector menu**

As part of CSR `ClientPivotControl` control (`clienttemplates.js`) is intended for rendering *View selector menu*, `SurfacedPivotCount` property defines the amount of view menu options rendered horizontally (default value is `3`)

### How to display custom amount of view options for List View using CSR

The following template demonstrates how to override `SurfacedPivotCount` property in order to display *4 view menu options*:

```
function renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames){
    var viewData = eval(renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
    ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = 4;   
    return RenderHeaderTemplate(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames); //render default Header template
}

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  Templates: {
    Header: renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments
  }
});
```

### How to apply the changes

There are at least two options how to apply the changes:

1. Using [JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx) of XLV web part
2. Place JavaScript template on page via `Script Editor`/`Content Editor`
   web parts

Here is how to apply the changes using the **second option**:

1. Switch the page (`NewForm.aspx`) into edit mode
2. Add `Script Editor` webpart right below the list view web part.
3. Put the specified code by wrapping it using `script` tag code into the Script Editor, for example: `<script type="text/javascript">{Template JS code goes here}</script>`
4. Save the page

### Result

[image]

Comment: Sorry to comment on old discussion. May I know can I change the sorting order in view selector by CSR?

Comment: @Mark, that sounds like a good question, would you mind to create a new question?

Comment: @VadimGremyachev I posted new question [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162875/how-to-change-the-sorting-order-in-view-selector)

Comment: @Mark, i've posted an answer [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/162934/10610)

Comment: @VadimGremyachev do you know if this is possible for discussion post replies (or indeed other areas where call outs are used)? I have posted a question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193071/expand-call-out-menu-options-on-page-load

Comment: At what point during the page load does this snippet need to be executed? I've added it as a function listed in `_spOnBodyLoadFunctionNames`, as I do with all custom JavaScript in my SharePoint site, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 6):

I do not think that can be done. It shows the 4th view only once we click on it. (Dynamic HTML)

But I found a workaround.

1. Go to Edit Page.
2. Click on Add web part and add a content editor with the links to all 4 views.
3. Edit list view web part and disable the view selector menu. Also if needed, set tool bar to no tool bar and remove search. (Look where to edit using screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, It seems like such a simple modification I figured there would be a way, but guess not...

Comment: These html injection scripts are frustrating to customize