# Is there a way for more then three view name to appear?

Tags: 2013, view

Currently I have only three views appear is there a way for all the view names to appear or more then three?

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript:

```
function renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames){
    var viewData = eval(renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
    ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = 4;   
    return RenderHeaderTemplate(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames); //render default Header template
}

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  Templates: {
    Header: renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments
  }
});
```

Reference link: [How to display more than 3 views in document library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112543/how-to-display-more-than-3-views-in-document-library)

Comment: I  added web part (script editor) and added the code but it didn't work.