# How to change the sorting order in view selector?

Tags: list-view, client-side-rendering

On a document library (under SP2013) we have created multiple views. In the view selector, the default view is listed at leftmost. All the other views are sorted in alphabetical order based on the view name.

Our user would like to determine the sorting order of view selector. Take below screenshot as example, how can we put the view selector in this order:

Deeds - Permits - All Documents - Agreements

[image]

P.S. I have read [How to display more than 3 views in document library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112543/how-to-display-more-than-3-views-in-document-library) and seems a good start but not exactly answer my question.

Comment: Its a very interesting question. A screen shot of what you have and what you want would make it great at first sight and draw more attention.

Comment: I cannot prepare a picture so I re-use the picture in old post.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no out of the box way to sort the list of views for a document library or list. They are sorted alphabetically by default. Annoying,  yes.

You only really have one option: since the views are sorted alphabetically, you can name your views so that they start with a number, e.g. 1.All Items, 2.Overdue Items, etc.

A *possible* second option could be to some how tap into the function that is called when the ellipses is clicked `ClientPivotControlExpandOverflowMenu(event)`, but this might just lead you to a dead end.