# Document Library Menu not showing as desired

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, sharepoint-addin

This is the view of the document library on the default "All Documents" tab. This is how I want the tabs to be displayed:

[image]

However whenever I click an option other than "All Documents" it gets shortened to only 2 options which is really annoying. I want it to stay as the original full menu showing all the tabs.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this? I couldn't find in the page edit settings anywhere that dealt with this. Perhaps there's a Javascript function that can sort it out?

Comment: Try looking at this questionhttp://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112543/how-to-display-more-than-3-views-in-document-library

Comment: I used a method similar to the one zingwing mentioned. I used a different script though... "<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(overrideSurfacePivotCount, 'clienttemplates.js');

function overrideSurfacePivotCount() {
   ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = 8;
};
</script>"

Answer (score 0):

Try to alter the width of the Webpart or add the same number columns as in your All Documents view so that the width will be adjusted.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.